# Jmeter: Segregate result error count based on Assertion

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, web-api-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am performing a performance test on my API using Jmeter. I have 3 assertions

1. 200 ok
2. duration limit under 3s
3. example.jsonpath.result = "OK"

I am getting the error as a total percentage
[image: Error %]

I want my error% to be segregated according to type of assertion in the exported csv.

like i was able to do int postman

[image: Post Man error segregation]

can i achieve this using Jmeter

Answer (score 1):

It is not achievable via any of existing [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Listeners)

The options are in:

1. JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) is a normal [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) so you can export it into [MS Excel](https://www.office.com/launch/Excel) or equivalent and come up with formulae displaying the statistics you need
2. You can use [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) to send the data to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) and then come up with [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) dashboard showing the statistics you need
3. You can [create your own Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) as JMeter architecture is modular and open for extension